# How to start service automatically at specific time every day in Android?

Tags: android

I have implemented service activity in my app which is i want to fetch the data in the background of application while my app is not opened infront.But right now i want to start the service at particular or specific time like today my service is start at 12pm , after that my service is start at 12am everyday, how to do this.Can someone help me.Thanks to appreciate.

Comment: Use alarm Manager and schedule your service.

Comment: Have you googled at all? --> [**AlarmManager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Answer (score 1):

As the comments state, `AlarmManager` is the class you're looking for. However it's not a great idea to start a service at an EXACT time, because if your app is popular and you have a million users, they're all going to hit your backend at exactly midday every day... Read more about the right way to do it here:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html